# Is it possible to create an alias for an enum in C / Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c

Example:

I find the enum `UIViewAnimationCurve` is too long. I want to write `CurveEaseIn`.

So I attempted to create an alias:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CurveEase) {
    CurveEaseInOut = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
    CurveEaseIn = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,
    CurveEaseOut = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
};
```

When I use my new enum in places where I need to specify `UIViewAnimationCurve`, I have to cast it otherwise Xcode throws warnings like:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CurveEase' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationCurve' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve')
```

I also tried:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(UIViewAnimationCurve, CurveEase) {
    CurveEaseInOut = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
    CurveEaseIn = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,
    CurveEaseOut = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
};
```

Notice the `UIViewAnimationCurve` as type of the enum. This gives the error:

```
Non-integral type 'UIViewAnimationCurve' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve') is an invalid underlying type
```

So it seems I am stuck with NSInteger as the type. But is there any way to trick the compiler into accepting CurveEase without doing a cast, and without suppressing warnings?

Comment: In C: `typedef enum {foo, bar, baz} my_enum;`.

Comment: What about `#define CurveEaseInOut  UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` ?

Comment: Is your code completion broken? :)

Comment: Mike no it is not. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `typedef UIAnimationCurve CurveEase` ?